# Display the date difference between two text field input without refreshing page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two field in the form which are mention in below:-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="training_start_date" value=""> 
        to 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="training_end_date" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need when we give the date in two field then output can be get in the same page in this place:

```html
Duration: <!-- Display the difference of those dates without refreshing -->
```

I am feel glad and thankful if anyone give the concept about to do this requirement.

Comment: Ok, that's the specification, what have you tried in order to fulfil it?

Comment: I think need the Ajax to display it.

Comment: Why would you need AJAX? Is the data being read from the server? Also, please add the code you've tried yourself to solve the problem. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Because I need the difference between two date by giving the input from that two field without refreshing the pages.

Comment: you can read the field values with JavaScript. After that, computing the difference should be easy, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this?

HTML:

```
<!-- JQuery and JQuery UI -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input id="date1" type="text" class="form-control" name="training_start_date" value="">to
        <input id="date2" type="text" class="form-control" name="training_end_date" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<br> <span> Diff:</span>  <span id='diff'> - </span>  <span> Days</span>
```

JS:

```
$('#date1').datepicker();
$('#date2').datepicker();

$('#date2').change(function () {
    var diff = $('#date1').datepicker("getDate") - $('#date2').datepicker("getDate");
    $('#diff').text(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1);
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/dLtp0k1u/

**EDIT**

Based on your comment:
No manual download needed here. It's just referencing hosted libraries.

Use this in a simple html page:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <!-- JQuery and JQuery UI -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input id="date1" type="text" class="form-control" name="training_start_date" value="">to
                <input id="date2" type="text" class="form-control" name="training_end_date" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <span> Diff:</span>
        <span id='diff'> - </span>
        <span> Days</span>

        <script>
            $('#date1').datepicker();
            $('#date2').datepicker();

            $('#date2').change(function () {
                var diff = $('#date1').datepicker("getDate") - $('#date2').datepicker("getDate");
                $('#diff').text(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But need to download the datepicker

Comment: What do you mean? Cannot reference JQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have majority of your problems solved...

1. Change the type to 'date' for all your inputs. Like this:
   http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date
2. Use the HTML onblur attribute so that your function runs every time the input box is out of focus.
3. Use the code below to calculate Date Difference.
    **Code Credit:**http://ditio.net/2010/05/02/javascript-date-difference-calculation/

   var DateDiff = {

   ```
       inDays: function(d1, d2) {
           var t2 = d2.getTime();
           var t1 = d1.getTime();

           return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
       },

       inWeeks: function(d1, d2) {
           var t2 = d2.getTime();
           var t1 = d1.getTime();

           return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000*7));
       },

       inMonths: function(d1, d2) {
           var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
           var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
           var d1M = d1.getMonth();
           var d2M = d2.getMonth();

           return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
       },

       inYears: function(d1, d2) {
           return d2.getFullYear()-d1.getFullYear();
       }
   }

   var dString = "May, 20, 1984";

   var d1 = new Date(dString);
   var d2 = new Date();

   document.write("<br />Number of <b>days</b> since "+dString+": "+DateDiff.inDays(d1, d2));
   document.write("<br />Number of <b>weeks</b> since "+dString+": "+DateDiff.inWeeks(d1, d2));
   document.write("<br />Number of <b>months</b> since "+dString+": "+DateDiff.inMonths(d1, d2));
   document.write("<br />Number of <b>years</b> since "+dString+": "+DateDiff.inYears(d1, d2));
   ```